# Reason for gravitational force

Tags: gravity

What is the reason for the existence of gravitational force between two bodies? Why do we say it as an attractive force? What makes any two objects to attract each other?

Comment: What is the reason for *any* force?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would spacetime curvature cause gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102910/)