# Is Earth flat according to Einstein?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, earth

I didnt understand how to apply general relativity to Earth. If there is no such a thing as gravity but spacetime bending. Can someone just show, send something to read how gravity works in Earth according to general relativity? Why people don't fall from earth? I think that the idea is there is no difference between gravity and accelerating up. But what about southern hemisphere?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity

Comment: I can sort of see what you are asking, but is it really too hard to say "away from the centre" instead of "up" ?  You have then answered your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102910/123208 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3009/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring  thanks. That was what i looking for.